# Query phone numbers

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception, android-contacts

I'm learning how to develop android apps. But I'm having a hard time retrieving the contacts' phones.

I was able to list all the contacts with the following code:

```
private static final String[] contactProjetion = new String[]{
        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
};

private void getContacts() {
    Cursor cursorContacts = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactProjetion, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
    while (cursorContacts.moveToNext()) {
        String id = cursorContacts.getString(0);
        String name = cursorContacts.getString(1);
        String hasPhone = cursorContacts.getString(2);
    }
}
```

But when searching for the contacts' phones using the same logic:

```
                String[] phoneProjetion = new String[]{
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
                };
                Cursor cursorPhone = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, phoneProjetion, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                while (cursorContacts.moveToNext()) {
                    String phone = cursorPhone.getString(1); // this line throw android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException
                }
```

I am having the following exception:

```
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 2
```

can anybody help me?

Comment: Do I really need to do two queries to retrieve contacts' phone numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are trying to access the wrong cursor.

Basically the message is saying you are trying to access the row from **cursorPhone** that is before the first row (position **-1**). That is because no **move** directive has been issued to the **cursorPhone** cusror, rather you are issuing the moves (iterating through) the **cursorContacts** cursor.

instead of :-

```
            while (cursorContacts.moveToNext()) {
                String phone = cursorPhone.getString(1); // this line throw android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException
            }
```

I think you should be using :-

```
            while (cursorPhone.moveToNext()) { //<<<< CHANGED
                String phone = cursorPhone.getString(1); // this line throw android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException
            }
```

Comment: This is a ctrl+c ctrl+v issue :D